# Convert comma separated to a array in datatable

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

How to convert comma separated values into an array in data table. I have a data table with a column as comma separated i want to convert it into array how to achieve that

```
Column1 Column2   Column3
  1      AA,AB,AC  Test
  2      AB,XB,LC  Test1
  3      PB,LB,KC  Test
```

I want the datatable with column2 as an array

```
     Column1 Column2          Column3
      1     ["AA","AB","AC"]  Test
      2     ["AB","XB","LC"]  Test1
      3     ["PB","LB","KC"]  Test


       string[] results = new string[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
       for (int index = 0; index < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; index++)
      {
               results[index] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[index][columnIndex].ToString();
      }
```

i have tried the above code but this converts the entire column. i need the conversion row by row for that column

Comment: `[Column].ToString().Split(',');`

Comment: At first you must exactly define the format of your file. Because the array in column 2 is comma separated, but how are the columns separated from each other?

Comment: Can you post some sample code that you have tried and isn't working?

Comment: can you share table designed and what you have tried so far??

Comment: @ Benjamin Drolet i have edited the post with sample code

Comment: @Shakir Ahamed the datatable is populated from database based on a query, i tried to change the comma separated to an array in stored proc but i find it very complicated, because that column is populated from a sub-query and i am using STUFF to create comma seperated values